# Silverstripe: Fulltext search?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

It seems that if you install Silverstripe 4.3 with a standard template (I tried several) there is no onsite full search. The input box is not appearing. What are the necessary steps to activate the onsite search?

Answer (score 2):

There's a module that provides full text search of a SilverStripe CMS website. It also has a quick start guide that should be a sufficient starting point:

https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-fulltextsearch/blob/master/docs/en/01_getting_started.md#quick-start

Comment: There's also a lighter fulltext search option which comes out of the box and doesn't require SOLR, although it's not compatible with Fluent for example at the moment: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/search/fulltextsearch/ =)

Comment: Thank you, I will try the offered solution today. The search guide will not help as I am using Fluent right now.